# Get the percentage frequency of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to know how I can get the percentage of frequencies from the dataframe below but only from column '1' and not getting the NaN?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A': ['foo', 'bar', 'g2g', 'g2g', 'g2g',
                                'bar', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', bat],
                   'B': ['0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0'] })

dfg = df.groupby(['A','B'])
df2 = dfg.size().unstack()
df2
>>
B   0   1
A       
bar 4.0 1.0
foo 3.0 NaN
g2g NaN 3.0
```

**Expected percentage**

```
bar 36.3% 9.0%
foo 27.7% NaN
g2g NaN  27.7%
```

**output: Desired result**

```
bar 9.0%
g2g 27.7%
```

Comment: `df[df.B == '1'].A.value_counts() / len(df)` ?

Comment: Something like `df.loc[df['B'] == '1', 'A'].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100).round(1).astype(str).add('%')`?

Comment: Also where are these percentages coming from? The shown DataFrame and counts don't seem to correspond to the shown percentages.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['NameOfColumn'].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100
```

Don't worry about Nan or null being counted . `dropna` will automatically ignore null or NaN values as stated here in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)